# Ошибка 404 на страницах магазина при использовании WooCommerce и Polylang

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня такая проблема: я хотел многоязычный сайт, и использовал плагин [Polylang](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/). Все страницы нормально отображаются, но когда иду на страницу продуктов, сингл-страницу продуктов и страницу таксономии данного продукта - всегда выдаёт ошибку 404. Эти страницы WordPress не находит.

Данный `post_type` создаётся автоматически от плагина WooCommerce. Я посмотрел очень много форумов и попробовал очень много чего, плагины, коды и т.д., но без толку. Я думаю нужно как-то заставить WooCommerce заставить понимать переведённые страницы, где в url есть это (`/en/`, `/hy/`, `/ru/`).

Answer (score 1):

### Общая информация

Во-первых, существует плагин [**Woocommerce-Polylang-Integration**](https://github.com/gdarko/Woocommerce-Polylang-Integration) для превентивного решения этой проблемы. Возможно, он поможет вам и в текущей ситуации.

Во-вторых, существует статья: "[**How To Make WooCommerce & Polylang Work Together**](https://jesperlundnielsen.dk/how-to-make-woocommerce-work-with-polylang-wordpress/)", которая позволяет решить последствия описанной вами проблемы.

Ниже будет мой вольный перевод выдержки из этой статьи.

### Предупреждение

Автор отмечает, что нижеследующее решение, возможно, не самое лучшее и следует проверять его работоспособность после каждого обновления плагина WooCommerce и Polylang, поскольку меняется исходный код WooCommerce.

### Исправление

1. Откройте файл `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-page-functions.php` в любом удобном вам текстовом редакторе.
2. Выполните поиск по файлу по этой строке: `wc_get_page_id( $page )`
3. Найдите эту строку кода:

   ```
   $page = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_' . $page . '_page_id', get_option('woocommerce_' . $page . '_page_id' ) );
   ```

   И замените ее следующим кодом:

   ```
   $page = function_exists('pll_get_post') ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_' . $page . '_page_id', pll_get_post ( get_option('woocommerce_' . $page . '_page_id' ) ) ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_' . $page . '_page_id', get_option('woocommerce_' . $page . '_page_id' ) );
   ```

### Как работает это исправление?

Данный код проверяет, установлен ли плагин Polylang и существует ли функция `pll_get_post`. Если вышеописанное верно, WooCommerce будет искать локализованную страницу, в противном случае, используется стандартная страница.

### Что делать, если не помогло?

[**Прочитать оригинальную статью от Jesper Lund**](https://jesperlundnielsen.dk/how-to-make-woocommerce-work-with-polylang-wordpress/). Там есть инструкция в картинках, как правильно настроить Polylang и WooCommerce.

Comment: Я делал все эти изменении, и плагин пробовал, всё безтолку...